# BS4 Dropdown malfunction on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown menu on my site that works on my computer but on mobile, the moment you open the dropdown menu the main menu closes... the site is currently live on https://www.devtechprojects.co.za.

```html
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header id="main-header" class="header-fancy">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="#">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="ion-navicon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="index.php">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  Services
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="webdev.php">Web Development</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="internet.php">Internet Services</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="designing.php">Designing</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="info-share">
              <li><a href="tel:0731885766"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://web.facebook.com/devtechprojects"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.php"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your markup looks fine, which means we probably can't help much. Something else must be acting on it. Your site is blocked on my network, so I can't go look at it.

Comment: What could cause such a problem other than my code? I didn't edit the js at all and only edited minor things in css ( nothing that could do this ).